# To store or not no to store original Typescript code in published node_module library?

Tags: javascript, typescript

When I write node_module in Typescript and publish it, I could publish only transpiled(obfuscated code) aka `/dist` folder. But I also can publish the original code (aka `/src` or `/lib` folders).

- If I publish only obfuscated code - the library gets thinner and it is more a `blackbox`.
- If I publish obfuscated and original code - it is bigger and it is possible to reason about this code (debug, study, understand it, see comments, etc).

What will be more classical approach to it? I have seen some modules with original code and without it.

Are there standards about it? Is node_module with original Typescript code is less `production ready`?

thank you

Comment: Do you want other people to use and modify your code or do you want other people to use and modify your code *easier*?

Comment: @VLAZ sure, why not?

Answer (score 1):

You should not include your pre-compiled code into the module, because there are no benefits from it.

- If someone wants to use your product, they want the small/fast version of it not the source code, that they have to compile themselves
- If they want to work with you, they will go to the git repository, where they can see the original source

I would suggest you to add these options to your `tsconfig` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
     "outDir": "./dist",          /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
     "declaration": true,         /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
  }
}
```

The `outDir` setting will specify, that all generated sources will be compiled in a specific folder at the root. This way, your generated code **can** only be at one location.

The `declaration` setting will generate so called "source-mapping" files. With that you can publish the compiled code, but still provide types for typescript users.

In your Git Repo, I would only keep the original source files and add the generated source folder to your `.gitignore`. In this case add the `dist` folder to the ignore-file.

Comment: well, this doesn't say anything about original source, should it be included or not

Comment: No it should not.